# What is the best way to use HTTP 2 with AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http2, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a Ruby on Rails App hosted on AWS using Elastic-beanstalk which works with HTTP 1 now I want to use HTTP 2. Can someone suggest me the best approach

Answer (score 7):

If I remember correctly when you add a new load balancer to your Elastic Beanstalk environment, it defaults to using a `Classic Load Balancer`, which doesn't support `HTTP/2`, I think the solution would be using an `Application Load Balancer` that does support it, you can find this info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/features/). You can also specify it while creating your environment as you can see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html#environments-cfg-alb-console). This will only allow `HTTP/2` communication between the client and the `ALB`, [your `ALB` will convert those `HTTP/2` requests into `HTTP/1.1` to communicate with your instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-configuration).

As seen [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=263770): `"If end-to-end HTTP/2 is a requirement for your application you can use a Layer 4 ELB ( Classic Load Balancer with TCP listener or Network Load Balancer). If you are interested also in SSL offloading the only option for now is Classic Load Balancer with an SSL listener."`